# Timely automatic unexpected reboot on ubuntu desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu

We have a remote linux server (ubuntu desktop). The system log indicates the system has been restarted on the timely fashion. Here is a part of the `last` output:

```
ut       pts/0        192.169.50.2-sta Sat Nov 24 22:17   still logged in
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Sat Nov 24 22:04 - 22:17  (00:13)
ut       pts/0        server.local     Sat Nov 24 21:36 - crash  (00:27)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Sat Nov 24 15:55 - 22:17  (06:21)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Fri Nov 23 18:02 - 22:17 (1+04:14)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Fri Nov 23 10:39 - 22:17 (1+11:38)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Fri Nov 23 04:18 - 22:17 (1+17:59)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Fri Nov 23 03:57 - 22:17 (1+18:20)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Thu Nov 22 20:38 - 22:17 (2+01:38)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Thu Nov 22 11:13 - 22:17 (2+11:03)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Thu Nov 22 08:12 - 22:17 (2+14:05)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Wed Nov 21 11:16 - 22:17 (3+11:00)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Tue Nov 20 22:36 - 22:17 (3+23:41)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Tue Nov 20 14:12 - 22:17 (4+08:05)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Tue Nov 20 11:32 - 22:17 (4+10:44)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Tue Nov 20 01:52 - 22:17 (4+20:25)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Tue Nov 20 00:22 - 22:17 (4+21:55)
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-21-generi Mon Nov 19 17:27 - 22:17 (5+04:50)
```

It looks the system is set to be restarted at `22:17`. Can anyone guide me why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the day count in the last column.

The integers before the recognizable time field are days. If you do the math, you'll realize that all those were sessions that were kicked out at the same reboot.